# Connecting Power BI to Azure SQL database without on-premises gateway running

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have recently started using MS Power BI, and have come across a problem which seems inconsistent, and the answer likewise.
I am connecting to an Azure SQL database, and therefore have chosen this as the data source in the desktop app. Everything seems to be working just fine, and I can create tables, graphs and whatnot. One thing is off, though: When I choose Azure SQL DB as the source, the connection dialog box does not appear to be any different than if I just choose (non-Azure) SQL DB. Puzzling.
The other thing, which is actually the main issue: In Power BI (the website), I can open my published reports, but some of them don't show up, and I get an error message in a pink bar at the top, saying the data source is not available because the gateway can't be reached. I am well aware of this, because I have deliberately stopped the gateway service (PBIEgwService) running locally, because I have read several places that if the data source is Azure, an on-premises gateway is not needed. (E.g.: "Question: Do I need a gateway for cloud data sources like Azure SQL Database?
Answer: No! The service will be able to connect to that data source without a gateway." here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem-faq)

So in short: Why does PBI not (always) connect directly to Azure?
And yes, I have checked the credentials. I can connect just fine in PBI desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowing Azure Services to connect in your Azure SQL firewall?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-server-level-ip-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are suggesting is that Power BI needs to be allowed to access the Azure SQL Database. That makes sense, given that all other users that need to connect to the DB need to have their IP addresses whitelisted. But how do I know which IP address the Power BI service has?

Comment: You will not know, that is why we have an option for allowing All Azure services.  This will essentially allow any Azure IP address to get access through the firewall, you will of course still have DB level auth.

Comment: All Azure Services is pretty broad. Security divisions in large companies don't like it. Is there a way to just restrict it to the Power BI service?

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Ken's answer. You must allow the IP range of both Power BI and Power Query to access your SQL Server. To obtain the IP range, you can use the [Azure services tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#available-service-tags) of Power BI and Power Query, which automatically includes the IP ranges of these two services.

If it is not possible to use services tags, you can use the [hard coded list of IP addresses](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) for both services. But you will need a routine to update these IPs.